# Flutter Animated Container

Tags: flutter

I have a `RaisedButton` widget and an `AnimatedContainer` widget in a screen, and the idea is that upon pressing the `RaisedButton` the width of the `AnimatedContainer` would then decrease in a given duration. The documentation of the `AnimatedContainer` states that all I would need to do is declare the width of the widget as a variable, and then `setState(() {})` after changing the value and it will automatically change to that value during the duration. I have tried to implement this and upon pressing the `RaisedButton` the variables value definitely changes (based on printing the value of it after pressing it), however the widget's width does not change with it. Am I missing something obvious?

My Widgets are within a container in a `PageView` and my code for the `RaisedButton` and `AnimatedContainer` is as follows:

```
RaisedButton (
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      loginWidth = 70.0;
    });
  },
),
AnimatedContainer (
 duration: new Duration (seconds: 2),
 width: loginWidth,
 height: 40,
 color: Colors.red,
)
```

Here is my widget tree:

```
pages.add(
      Container(
        color: chSecondary,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container (
              child: Align (
                child: Image(image: AssetImage("graphics/signin.png")),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              ),
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 100, start: 15, end: 15, bottom: 15),
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container (
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage("graphics/login.png"), height: 200, width: 200,),
                      margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 20),
                    ),
                    Container (
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Column (
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            child: new Text("Email:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: tonSubTitle, color: Colors.black)),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            child: new TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              controller: _email,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: tonText, color: Colors.black),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(tonRadius)),
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 15, start: 7.5),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                                hintText: "Email Address",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return "Please enter an email";
                                }
                                if (!value.contains("@tonbridge-school.org")) {
                                  return "Please enter a valid email address";
                                }
                              },

                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10)
                          ),
                          Align (
                            child: new Text("Password:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: tonSubTitle, color: Colors.black)),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            child: new TextFormField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              controller: _password,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: tonText),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 15, start: 7.5),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(tonRadius)),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                                hintText: "Password",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return "Please enter a password";
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10)
                          ),
                          RaisedButton (
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                loginWidth = 70.0;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          AnimatedContainer (
                            duration: new Duration (seconds: 2),
                            width: loginWidth,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you share more of your widget tree? The problem is not in your code snippet

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have edited the question and added my widget tree.

Comment: I had similar issue, it was because variable I was using to animate weren't global. I think animation doesn't work if variable scope is within the build method.

Comment: @Varundroid - That will work, but most of the time it's best if state variables are scoped to the state widget. If they are declared in a larger scope, you can get weird side effects if other running code mutates the value. 

Variables should be scoped as close to the builder method as possible, but not inside of it. 

See my answer below for example code snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet you've posted is **already correct**.
Make sure that:

- loginWidth is initialized
- the new loginWidth value is actually different from the default value

I've copied it and built a minimal example so you can double check the rest of your code. This example also include a surrounding **PageView**:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyBodyState createState() => _MyBodyState();
}

class _MyBodyState extends State<MyBody> {
  double loginWidth = 40.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton (
                child: Text('Animate!'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    loginWidth = 250.0;
                  });
                },
              ),
              AnimatedContainer (
                duration: Duration (seconds: 1),
                width: loginWidth,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used your code example to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious, and it once again does not work. What version of flutter are you using? Would my version of Android Studio / Xcode effect this in any way?

Comment: I'm on `Flutter (Channel master, v1.3.11-pre.39, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale de-DE)`. You're Flutter version could change something here, but Android Studio and Xcode shouldn't modify anything.

Comment: What is the chance that running on the beta would mean that animations wouldn't work? I am using it due to the fact that android keyboards don't work correctly in the last version of the master channel.

Comment: Don't know what the chances are, but you can change your version to master, look if it works, and then change it back to beta.

Answer (score 0):

do you initialised loginWidth ?

```
var loginWidth =0.0;
Curve _curve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;
_doanimation(){

setState(() {
    loginWidth ==0.0? loginWidth =100: loginWidth =0.0;
   });
}
```

*change function with your case*

```
    Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("welcome"),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  _doanimation();
                },
              ),
              AnimatedContainer(
                curve: _curve,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                width: loginWidth,
                height:100

              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: I have tried this and once again it does not do the animation. Could this be something to do with the fact that it is within a PageView

Comment: `PageView`should not be a problem. In my example above I used too, the `PageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have loginWidth declared? It needs to outside the scope of the builder function or its value will get reinitialized on every build.

Can you update your example to show where you declare?

Correct:

```
class _WidgetState extends State<Widget> {
  double loginWidth = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return the new widget tree
  }
}
```

Incorrect:

```
class _WidgetState extends State<Widget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double loginWidth = 0;

    //return the new widget tree
  }
}
```